# How to call mysql stored procedure with dynamic name in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have requirement like to call the stored procedures to get the data, here i will get the stored procedure name through post data.

I tried using GString but no use, Can any one help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should include more information, such as examples of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird one, but possible. Grails/GORM doesn't provide a way to execute stored procedures. It's just not part of ORM functionality. And neither does Hibernate. But, Hibernate does provide access to a JDBC connection. So you can get a connection from [Hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html), then create a Groovy [Sql](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html) instance with the connection, and finally execute your stored procedure. Here's an example:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

SomeDomainClass.withNewSession { session ->
    session.doWork { java.sql.Connection connection ->
        def sql = new Sql(connection)

        sql.call("YOUR STORED PROCEDURE SQL HERE")
    }
}
```

It works like this:

1. Using any of your domain classes, call `withSession(Closure)` to get a Hibernate session.
2. With the session, call `doWork(Work)` to get access to the session's JDBC connection. Now, `doWork(Work)` expects an implementation of **org.hibernate.jdbc.Work**. But, if I recall correctly, Groovy can take a closure with the same parameters and coerce it to implement the interface.
3. Using the connection, create an instance of Sql. You could skip this and query with Java, but Groovy's Sql class is so nice.
4. Use one of the available `Sql.call()` methods to execute your stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

In postgress SQL, it is posible to call stored procedure. The catch is returning a data table so that you can map it to a model. This is as shown bellow.

```
create function activate(confirmationcode text)
  returns TABLE(resultid integer, resultmessage character varying)
language plpgsql
as $$
BEGIN
 ....
END
```

This can be invoked as follows in GORM db connections

```
type FuncResult struct {
    Resultid      int
    Resultmessage string
}
...
fResult := FuncResult{}
err := s.db.Raw("SELECT * from  activate(?)", token).Scan(&fResult).Error
```